# Short routes in vehicle routing problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, operations-research

Consider the [vehicle routing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem) (VRP), which poses the question of what the optimal set of routes for a fleet of vehicles to traverse in order to deliver to a given set of customers is.

In the classical problem, we seek to minimize the total distance traveled across all vehicles. Instead, I am considering a variant of the problem in which we primarily seek to minimize the *number of vehicles* and secondarily seek to minimize the total distance.

In this variant, we have a few break time constraints. In particular, these constraints depend on how long a route takes. If a route takes less than $4$ hours, then no break is required. If a route takes between $4$ and $8$ hours, then there will be a $30$ minute break required. Finally, if a vehicle's time exceeds $6$ hours, then a $60$ minute break is required (just to be clear: if a route takes $7$ hours, we'd require only a break of $60$ minutes and not $60 + 30 = 90$ minutes). No route can exceed $8$ hours.

My question is the following: Is it ever possible to do better (i.e. use fewer vehicles) with shorter routes as opposed to longer routes? I am pretty sure the answer is no. I can't come up with a counterexample. If the answer is no, is it possible to show that it's never possible to do better? I would like the triangle inequality to be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible, particularly if driving time is not strictly proportional to distance between customers (which is normal). Consider the following two diagrams, which have the same depot (A) and customers (B through G). Returns to depot are not shown.

In the first diagram, there are four routes (black, red, green and blue). The black and blue routes are assumed to take long enough that there is only enough time after nodes C or E to make a beeline back to the depot. Similarly, the time between F and G is enough that it is not possible for one vehicle to cover both.

[image: four route solution]

In the second diagram, only three routes are used. The black and blue routes are shorter than in the first diagram. The red route is longer in geometric (distance) terms than either the red or green routes in the first diagram (but perhaps not longer than their combined lengths). It may involve less driving time than either of those routes (for instance, if the red route in the second diagram runs along a highway and the red and green routes in the first diagram use congested local roads with traffic lights).

[image: three route solution]

Comment: The coordinate system is euclidean, so distance is implied, but you need to keep several things in mind. (1) I just "free-handed" the diagram in a graphing program, without regard to specific coordinates. The images are intended to be the basis for you to find an appropriate example. (2) As I mentioned, I am not assuming that time is strictly proportional to distance. (3) You can always scale the coordinates to keep total distances under 8, if you do assume that distance = time. (4) You may need to fiddle with the example a little to get what you want.

Comment: I think you need to spell out your assumptions. Are you assuming that deliveries themselves take zero time (e.g., dropping items by parachute from drones)? Are you assuming that driving time is proportional to driving distance (not true anywhere I drive)? Are you assuming route distance equals euclidean distance (2-norm) between points (not true in midtown Manhattan, from personal experience)? As to the triangle inequality, I would assume drivers would take the fastest route between two points. That would automatically satisfy triangle in the time domain, but maybe not in the space domain.

Comment: Tweak my example so that points have integer coordinates (for instance, C = (-1, 5)). The first set of routes have total euclidean distances of 8.61 (black, blue) and 4.24 (red, green), with a total distance of 25.7. The second set have distances 6 (black, blue) and 7.1 (red), for a total distance of 19.1. I'm assuming return to base is not part of the eight hours, but that can be dealt with. As long as the vehicle speed and delivery times are such that 8.61 with two deliveries is feasible but 8.83 with three deliveries is not, I think the example works. If not, tell me why not.

Comment: Re the last bit, 8.83 would be A -> B -> F -> C or A -> D -> G -> E. If that's feasible, the initial four route solution is artificially bad, although I'm not sure that's a deal-breaker as far as the original question is concerned.

Comment: Is it possible to have the red route in the second figure be shorter than the smallest route in the first figure? So any route in the second diagram is smaller than any route in the first figure.

Comment: You could move C and E from ordinate 5 to ordinate 2, leaving everything else alone.